# JavaFX with FXML Tableview not displaying

Tags: javafx, fxml, observablelist

I've been searching all over for what I'm doing wrong but somehow I'm missing something. I've commented out and rewrote so much code that it's starting to be a mess (totally my fault) so hopefully I can find a solution.

I am using a FXML form to make a list of Attack class objects. The form pulls up, I type the required entries, hit the add attack button and the table does not populate.  Here is the pertinent code:

---

Classes involved

```
 public class Attack {

       import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Attack {

    private final SimpleStringProperty weapon = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleStringProperty range= new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleStringProperty damage= new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private int attackBonus;

    public String getRange(){return range.get();}
    public String getName(){return weapon.get();}
    public String getDamage(){return damage.get();}
    public int getAttackBonus(){return attackBonus;}

    public void setRange(String newRange){range.set(newRange);}
    public void setWeapon(String newName){weapon.set(newName);}
    public void setAttackBonus(int atkBonus){this.attackBonus = atkBonus;}
    public void setDamage(String dmg){damage.set(dmg);}




    Attack(String nameIn, int AB, String rangeIn, String damageIn){

      setWeapon(nameIn);
      setDamage(damageIn);
      setRange(rangeIn);
      setAttackBonus(AB);

    };

    Attack(){
       this("", 0, "", "");
    }
}
```

---

---

Controller Class

```
package sample;


import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AddNPC{

    @FXML
    private Button save, addAttack;

    @FXML
    private TextField ac, hp, init, initBonus, fort, will, ref, weapon, attackBonus, damage;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton melee, touch, ranged, rangedTouch;
    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup range;

    @FXML
    private NPC monster;

    @FXML
    private Stage dialogStage;

   @FXML
    private final TableView<Attack> attackTableView = new TableView<>();

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Attack, String> weaponColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Attack, String> attackColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Attack, String> rangeColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Attack, String> damageColumn;

    Dice d = new Dice(1, 3, 1);

   /* @FXML
    private final ObservableList<Attack> atk = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList<Attack> getAtk(){
        return atk;
    }*/


    //public AddNPC(){};

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){


        getAttack();



    }


    public ObservableList<Attack> getAttack(){
        ObservableList<Attack> attacks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        attacks.add(new Attack("Unarmed", 0, "melee", "1d3"));
        return attacks;
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event){


        //event for save here but not shown


        if(event.getSource() == addAttack){

            String weaponIn = weapon.getText();
            int bonusIn = Integer.parseInt(attackBonus.getText());
            String rangeIn = range.getSelectedToggle().getUserData().toString();
            String damageIn = damage.getText();

            Attack attack = new Attack(weaponIn, bonusIn, rangeIn, damageIn);



            attackTableView.getItems().add(attack);

            attackBonus.clear();
            weapon.clear();
            damage.clear();





        }

    }



}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="541.0" prefWidth="453.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.AddNPC">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="name" layoutX="70.0" layoutY="74.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="127.0" promptText="Name" />
      <TextField fx:id="hp" layoutX="71.0" layoutY="114.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="38.0" promptText="HP" />
      <TextField fx:id="ac" layoutX="125.0" layoutY="114.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="38.0" promptText="AC" />
      <TextField fx:id="init" layoutX="179.0" layoutY="114.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="68.0" promptText="Initiative" />
      <TextField fx:id="initBonus" layoutX="261.0" layoutY="114.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="98.0" promptText="Initiative Bonus" />
      <TextField fx:id="fort" layoutX="71.0" layoutY="153.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="38.0" promptText="Fort" />
      <TextField fx:id="will" layoutX="125.0" layoutY="153.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="38.0" promptText="Will" />
      <TextField fx:id="ref" layoutX="181.0" layoutY="153.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="57.0" promptText="Reflex" />
      <Button fx:id="save" layoutX="202.0" layoutY="502.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Save" />
      <Button fx:id="addAttack" layoutX="185.0" layoutY="293.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Add Attack" />
      <Label layoutX="159.0" layoutY="23.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="NPC Editor">
         <font>
            <Font size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>

      <Label layoutX="222.0" layoutY="228.0" text="+" />
      <TextField fx:id="weapon" layoutX="65.0" layoutY="224.0" promptText="Weapon Name" />
       <TextField fx:id="attackBonus" layoutX="232.0" layoutY="224.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="47.0" promptText="Bonus" />
      <TextField fx:id="damage" layoutX="292.0" layoutY="224.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="83.0" promptText="damage" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="melee" contentDisplay="TOP" layoutX="69.0" layoutY="253.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="75.0" selected="true" text="Melee" textAlignment="CENTER" userData="melee">
         <toggleGroup>
            <ToggleGroup fx:id="range" />
         </toggleGroup></RadioButton>

      <RadioButton fx:id="touch" layoutX="144.0" layoutY="262.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Touch" toggleGroup="$range" userData="touch" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="ranged" layoutX="214.0" layoutY="262.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Range" toggleGroup="$range" userData="ranged" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="rangedTouch" layoutX="279.0" layoutY="262.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Ranged Touch" toggleGroup="$range" userData="rangedTouch" />
      <Line endX="100.0" layoutX="222.0" layoutY="204.0" startX="-100.0" />
      <TableView fx:id="attackTableView" layoutX="18.0" layoutY="332.0" prefHeight="154.0" prefWidth="418.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="weaponColumn" prefWidth="107.0" text="Weapon">
            <cellValueFactory>
               <PropertyValueFactory property="weapon" /></cellValueFactory>
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn fx:id="attackColumn" prefWidth="69.0" text="Atk Bonus">
            <cellValueFactory>
              <PropertyValueFactory property="attackBonus" /></cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
           <TableColumn fx:id="rangeColumn" prefWidth="59.0" text="Range">
            <cellValueFactory>
              <PropertyValueFactory property="range" /></cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
           <TableColumn fx:id="damageColumn" prefWidth="181.0" text="Damage">
            <cellValueFactory>
              <PropertyValueFactory property="damage" /></cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
        </columns>

      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

---

Hopefully I'm not missing anything.

Comment: It's always a mistake to initialize `@FXML`-annotated fields. You should have `@FXML private TableView<Attack> attackTableView ;` **without** the `= new TableView<>()`. That probably won't fix the problem, but it will likely lead you to where the solution is.

Comment: You are also adding the columns to the table twice, and setting the cell value factories twice. Once in the FXML, and once in the initialize method.

Comment: Why do you use the same event handler for 2 completely different functionalities? Using 2 methods would be more logical than using a single method and checking, which button was clicked... Furthermore 2 of 4 properties do not exist in the attack class.

Comment: @James_D Thanks, it's a start. I tried taking off the "= new TableView<>() and get an error saying it might not have been initialized. The adding twice I have played with and I wasn't sure about.

Comment: @Fabian Took it from a tutorial, I agree with you and should fix it. Thanks for the advice. Which properties don't exist? That might be what I'm missing.

Comment: @Jason Huh? "Might not have been initialized" is a compile error for local variables, not for fields.

Comment: @Jason: `weapon` and `damage`.

Comment: @fabian they are called name and dice, I only called the fields that when making the form in scene builder. If you look in the function that takes the from and turns it into the attack class you can see they match up. I could change the variable names to match the column names I suppose.

Comment: @Jason they may be correct in the fxml, but that does not matter, if you replace the `cellValueFactory`s in the `initialize` method of the controller...

Comment: OK I made some changes to reflect most of the advice and to simplify things. I took out the dice class and just made it a string, and only adding the table in the FXML. Still not sure what's going on.

Comment: @fabian OK I fixed that.

Comment: I found the problem. When declared the table in the controller, it was declared as final. I figured it would be something simple.